# Why is my PowerShell script terminating too quickly?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, python

Hoping you can help me I have a very simple python script which sole purpose is to go through a load of excel workbooks and get the data and produce a single file from it. Script works great. I then put it on a server to run and i basically get an empty file. Could anyone tell me why this might be? I feel like I need to slow it down somehow like its exiting too quickly? I have tried time.sleep at various parts to slow the script down and also making a batch file to include pause in it. Can anyone help me?

Python script;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

class FileCombiner:

    def __init__(self,filetype):
        self.filetype = filetype
        self.master = pd.DataFrame()

    def get_files(self):
        self.files = glob.glob('X:\*'+self.filetype)

    def combine_files(self):
        for file in self.files:
                df = pd.read_excel(file)
                df = df.drop(['IN.1','OUT.1'],axis=1)
                df['Day'] = df['Day'].shift(-1)
                df['Date'] = df['Date'].shift(-1)
                df['IN'] = df['IN'].shift(-1)
                df['OUT'] = df['OUT'].shift(-1)
                df = df.dropna(subset = ['Employee Name & No.', 'Day'])
                self.master = self.master.append(df)

    def save_master(self):
        self.master.to_excel('E:\QlikData\Shared 
        Data\CovidWearables\Clock_Data\qlik_combined_data.xlsx')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    combiner = FileCombiner('xls')
    combiner.get_files()
    combiner.combine_files()
    combiner.save_master()
```

Powershell (PS1) file;

```
cd C:\PyScripts 
python clock_report_main.py
```

If I run the script manually as in I go into PowerShell CD into directory i need and then python clock_report_main.py I get a 220kb file. If I setup with windows scheduler like run this powershell file I get a 5kb file with headers and nothing else. Like I say my main strategy has been to try and slow the script down - so scheduler doesn't think its done and kill it but no beans. Any help hugely appreciated

Comment: Can you try putting an `r` before `'E:\QlikData\Shared Data\CovidWearables\Clock_Data\qlik_combined_data.xlsx'` like in `r'E:\QlikData\Shared Data\CovidWearables\Clock_Data\qlik_combined_data.xlsx'` (same for `r"X:\*"`) and try to run it on your server?

Comment: Plus, please put a `print(self.files)` after `self.files = glob.glob(r'X:\*'+self.filetype)` to see if globbing correctly finds files. In case not, this is silently ignored in your for loop in the `combine_files` function.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the r to make interpret the \ as literal - I also ensured that glob was picking up the files correctly which it is.

Comment: I think for now I shall do a dirty hack and just bung the main function in an infinite loop with a sleep for an hour at the bottom. Then when I have more time I shall do some error reporting into a txt file or introduce some logging to try and get to the bottom of what is going on. 
Thanks again.

Comment: It is indeed weird. Can you check the log of the scheduled task after it was run? (should work like this https://www.geeksengine.com/article/how-to-use-windows-task-scheduler-2.html - personally never needed it)

And looping the main function does the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea the main function does do the trick - and then I have basically left the terminal window open on the server (which I didn't really want to do for myriad reasons)
I shall get back to you on the log some point tonight - I am getting hassled by the powers that be as they need the data yesterday - so I shall have to play with fire for now and use this until I can properly figure out - sigh